# Using Hot Keys in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have written a application which runs in the background. I want to write a code 
so that, when "ctrl + Alt + Q" is pressed, i should prompt the user with a message box,
"Are you sure to log out?". It is a c# windows application.

Thanks.

Comment: Run a spell-check. It should be "sure" instead of "shure" (specifically for your app msgbox).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use PInvoke to register hot keys. Here is a post on [BlackWasp](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/RegisterHotKey.aspx) and this one by [Christian](http://www.liensberger.it/web/blog/?p=207) detailing the process.